# Using DefaultIfEmpty with an object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I saw an example on MSDN where it would let you specify the default value if nothing is returned.  See below:

```
List<int> months = new List<int> { };
int firstMonth2 = months.DefaultIfEmpty(1).First();
```

Is it possible to use this functionality with an object?  Example:

```
class object
{
  int id;
  string name;
}
```

code:

```
List<myObjec> objs = new List<myObjec> {};
string defaultName = objs.DefaultIfEmpty(/*something to define object in here*/).name;
```

**UPDATE:**

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
List<myObjec> objs = new List<myObjec> {};
string defaultName = objs.DefaultIfEmpty(new myObjec(-1,"test")).name;
```

But haven't been able to.  It should be noted that I am actually trying to use this method on an object defined in my DBML using LINQ-To-SQL.  Not sure if that makes a difference in this case or not.

Comment: Yes, of course. Have you tried it? Where’s the problem?

Comment: Maybe `new myObjec()` is what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference but this is a simplified version of something i'm doing in LinqToSQL.  I tried doing the equivalent of `new myObjec (-1,"test")` but it didn't work.

Comment: My problem is that i don't know what to put in the place of `/*something to define object in here*/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass an instantiated class as a parameter of the `DefaultIfEmpty`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lTest = new List<Test>();
        var s = lTest.DefaultIfEmpty(new Test() { i = 1, name = "testing" }).First().name;
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

To add to it and make it a bit more elegant (IMO) add a default constructor:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lTest = new List<Test>();
        var s = lTest.DefaultIfEmpty(new Test()).First().name;
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Test() { i = 2; name = "testing2"; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the MSDN page on this Extension Method you can do what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx

Check the sample on this page for an example on how to use this with an object.

Answer (score 1):

i must admit i am not too sure i understand your question, but i'll try to suggest using double question mark if the returned object might be null. Like so:

```
myList.FirstOrDefault() ?? new myObject();
```

Comment: First throws an exception if there are no elements in the list; you want `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a default Object Like this:

```
Object o_Obj_Default = new Object();
o_Obj_Default.id = 3;
o_Obj_Default.name = "C";
```

And add it to your default value :

```
string defaultName = objs.DefaultIfEmpty(o_Obj_Default).First().name;
```

If your list "objs" is empty, the result will be "C"

Comment: Sure, if you Object has constructor ; string defaultName = o_Objs.DefaultIfEmpty(new Object(1,"D")).First().Name;